# Pyexcelerate freeze panes

Tags: python, pyexcelerate

XlsxWriter has a method of adding frozen panes to an excel file:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('frozen_panes.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Panes 1')
worksheet1.freeze_panes(1, 0)
```

However, I have to use Pyexcelerate, and I can't find anything in their docs related to froze panes. Does Pyexcelerate have a similar method which would allow me to add frozen panes?

Comment: http://fossies.org/dox/picalo-4.94/classpicalo_1_1lib_1_1pyExcelerator_1_1BIFFRecords_1_1Window2Record.html

This class has options regarding freeze_panes

Comment: @JeD It's PyExcelerate I'm using, not PyExcelerator

Comment: Oh sorry. There is a freeze option in the panes class: https://github.com/kz26/PyExcelerate/blob/dev/pyexcelerate/Panes.py but I'm not sure how to use it. I'll tell you if I find s.th.

Comment: I believe you have to get the worksheet and then simply add a pane with freeze = true.. Try it ;)

Comment: @JeD Thats it! Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To whom it may concern:

The solution was to get a worksheet and add a Pane with the option `freeze = true`.

The class Pane can be seen here:

https://github.com/kz26/PyExcelerate/blob/dev/pyexcelerate/Panes.py

Answer (score 2):

```
import pyexcelerate
wb = pyexcelerate.Workbook()
ws = wb.new_sheet("sheet name")
# suppose you want to freeze rows 1-2 and columns A-D
rows = 2
columns = 4
ws.panes = pyexcelerate.Panes(columns, rows) # note order versus set_cell_value
wb.save("example_freeze_panes.xlsx")
```